# How to make UART communication using ST-Link V2?

Tags: serial-port, remote-debugging, uart, stm32f4

I have an STM32F417IG mcu connected with my PC. I use CoIDE and an ST-Link\v2 ISOL, to program and debug. I am looking for a way to connect serially to the target via the same setup. My motivation is that i want to send input to the board while I am debugging. Is it possible? Should i look for a driver that creates an interface and associates a virtual com port to the st-link/v2?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29045/st-link-is-serial-communication-possible

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206113/how-do-i-use-the-printf-function-on-stm32/279945#279945

Answer (score 2):

The user manual for STM32 Nucleo-64 boards might be an interesting starting point for you to find an answer.

Search for DM00105823 on www.st.com.

If you can risk working without electrical isolation you might also consider
buying a Nucleo-64 board (or something similar), cut off the Embedded ST-LINK/V2-1
from the Cuttable PCB and use this for debugging and UART communication instead of your ST-Link.

I'm also considering buying an ST-Link/v2 ISOL, but until now I could not
see if the virtual com port is also part of its features. 
The Embedded ST-LINK/V2-1 definitly has this feature.

Another approach for you could be to connect just any USB-TTL-Uart (FTDI...) with suitable voltage level to your UART-Lines (and GND of course). You can then use PuTTy or another terminal software to send input to your board.

Comment: IS this an example of what you are referring to? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07TXVRQ7V

Comment: Yes. This one seems to have selectable voltage levels (5V, 3.3V and 1.8V). Anyhow I would prefer an adapter where its easy to get the schematics of it.